# Reactive approach to simple imperative task

Tags: system.reactive, rx-java

Application requirements:

- subscribe to two event streams A and B
- for each A event there should be corresponding B event some time later
- the application monitors A events and alerts if no corresponding B arrives (in time)
- B events can arrive in a different order from the A events (but only after), late, or not at all

This is simple in a traditional approach:

- record each A event in a collection
- remove the A event when a corresponding B event arrives
- monitor the collection for A events that don't receive a B within timeout, and generate alerts

I would like to try a reactive solution but don't know which operators would express this best. I visualise event streams (Observables):

- stream of A
- stream of B
- perhaps also a stream of timer ticks (*unless the timing operators cater for this*)

with the final output being a set of alerts:

```
someObservable.
    ...incantations, other observables...
.subscribe ((EventA a) -> raiseAlertForMissingB (a));
```

Is there an elegant reactive approach, or is this just **not a good fit for rx**?

*(subsequent addition to original question)*

The ascii art  marble diagram could look like this

```
A stream A1----A2----------A3------------------A4--------------A5---------
B stream ------------B1------------B3---------------B4------------B5-----
                                            (A2 TIMEOUT) 
merged   ------------A1B1----------A3B3------A2??---A4B4----------A5B5---
```

The subscriber receives tuples from the merged stream. If the tuple is a matching A and B event, it gets logged, but if the tuple is an A event without matching B event (shown as A2?? in the marble diagram) the the subscriber raises an alert. Viola!

But how to trigger the timed wait for a matching B event for each A event?

*(Another addition)*

To illustrate the 4th requirement dot point section "B events can arrive in a different order from the A events (but only after)..."

```
A stream A6----A7----------A8----------------------
B stream ------------B7------------B6-------B8-----
merged   ------------A7B7----------A6B6-----A8B8---
```

**Update 23/2/2016**

I am testing the proposed solutions ported to Java.

**Solution: Enigmativity**

```
public class Test06Enigmativity {
    private static final long A_PERIOD = 400;
    private static final long B_PERIOD = 500;
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 4_000;
    private static final int[] bOrder = {
        0, 1, 2,
        4,
        3,  // out of order
        6,
        5,  // out of order
        7, 8,
        10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        9,  // out of order
        15
    };

    private final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis ();

    public static void main (final String[] args) {
        Test06Enigmativity app = new Test06Enigmativity ();
        app.runEnigmativity ();
    }

    private void runEnigmativity () {
        Observable<Long> aStream =
            Observable.interval (A_PERIOD, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .doOnNext (seq -> {
                    output ("       A%s", seq);
                }).take (bOrder.length);

        Observable<Long> bStream =
            Observable.interval (B_PERIOD, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .map (seq -> {
                    long aId = (long) bOrder[seq.intValue ()];
                    output ("           B%s", aId);
                    return aId;
                })
                .take (bOrder.length);

        monitorEnigmativity (aStream, bStream, TIMEOUT)
            .subscribe (this::output);

        try {
            Thread.sleep (60_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    private Observable<String> monitorEnigmativity (Observable<Long> aStream, Observable<Long> bStream, int thresholdMsec) {
        return Observable.create (subscriber ->
            bStream.publish (pb ->
                Observable.merge (
                    aStream.map (ax ->
                        pb
                            .filter (pbx -> pbx.equals (ax))
                            .take (1)
                            .timeout (thresholdMsec, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Observable.defer (
                                () -> {
                                    output ("           timeout on B%s", ax);
                                    return Observable.just (-1L);
                                }
                            )).map (pbx -> String.format ("%s,%s", ax, pbx))
                    )
                )
            ).subscribe (subscriber::onNext)
        );
    }

    private void output (String format, Object... args) {
        System.out.printf ("tid:%3d %4dms %s%n", Thread.currentThread ().getId (), System.currentTimeMillis () - startTime,
            String.format (format, args));
    }
}
```

This works fine with:

```
private static final long A_PERIOD = 400;
private static final long B_PERIOD = 500;
private static final int TIMEOUT = 4_000;

tid: 12  511ms        A0
tid: 15  626ms            B0
tid: 15  626ms 0,0
tid: 12  907ms        A1
tid: 15 1126ms            B1
tid: 15 1126ms 1,1
tid: 12 1307ms        A2
tid: 15 1626ms            B2
tid: 15 1626ms 2,2
tid: 12 1707ms        A3
tid: 12 2107ms        A4
tid: 15 2126ms            B4
tid: 15 2126ms 4,4
tid: 12 2507ms        A5
tid: 15 2625ms            B3
tid: 15 2625ms 3,3
tid: 12 2907ms        A6
tid: 15 3126ms            B6
tid: 15 3126ms 6,6
tid: 12 3307ms        A7
tid: 15 3626ms            B5
tid: 15 3626ms 5,5
tid: 12 3707ms        A8
tid: 12 4107ms        A9
tid: 15 4126ms            B7
tid: 15 4126ms 7,7
tid: 12 4507ms        A10
tid: 15 4626ms            B8
tid: 15 4626ms 8,8
tid: 12 4908ms        A11
tid: 15 5127ms            B10
tid: 15 5128ms 10,10
tid: 12 5307ms        A12
tid: 15 5626ms            B11
tid: 15 5626ms 11,11
tid: 12 5707ms        A13
tid: 12 6107ms        A14
tid: 15 6126ms            B12
tid: 15 6126ms 12,12
tid: 12 6507ms        A15
tid: 15 6626ms            B13
tid: 15 6626ms 13,13
tid: 13 7109ms            timeout on B9
tid: 13 7114ms 9,-1
tid: 15 7126ms            B14
tid: 15 7126ms 14,14
tid: 15 7625ms            B9
tid: 15 8126ms            B15
tid: 15 8126ms 15,15
```

But with B's arriving close to the A's, events can be missed:

```
private static final long A_PERIOD = 400;
private static final long B_PERIOD = 410;
private static final int TIMEOUT = 2_000;

tid: 12  509ms        A0
tid: 15  538ms            B0
tid: 12  905ms        A1
tid: 15  948ms            B1
tid: 15  948ms 1,1
tid: 12 1305ms        A2
tid: 15 1358ms            B2
tid: 15 1358ms 2,2
tid: 12 1706ms        A3
tid: 15 1768ms            B4
tid: 12 2105ms        A4
tid: 15 2178ms            B3
tid: 15 2178ms 3,3
tid: 12 2505ms        A5
tid: 16 2538ms            timeout on B0
tid: 16 2544ms 0,-1
tid: 15 2588ms            B6
tid: 12 2905ms        A6
tid: 15 2998ms            B5
tid: 15 2998ms 5,5
tid: 12 3305ms        A7
tid: 15 3408ms            B7
tid: 15 3408ms 7,7
tid: 12 3705ms        A8
tid: 15 3817ms            B8
tid: 15 3817ms 8,8
tid: 12 4105ms        A9
tid: 14 4106ms            timeout on B4
tid: 14 4106ms 4,-1
tid: 15 4228ms            B10
tid: 12 4505ms        A10
tid: 15 4638ms            B11
tid: 12 4905ms        A11
tid: 16 4906ms            timeout on B6
tid: 16 4906ms 6,-1
tid: 15 5048ms            B12
tid: 12 5305ms        A12
tid: 15 5457ms            B13
tid: 12 5705ms        A13
tid: 15 5868ms            B14
tid: 12 6106ms        A14
tid: 13 6107ms            timeout on B9
tid: 13 6107ms 9,-1
tid: 15 6279ms            B9
tid: 14 6510ms            timeout on B10
tid: 12 6510ms        A15
tid: 14 6510ms 10,-1
tid: 15 6688ms            B15
tid: 15 6688ms 15,15
```

B0 arrived but yielded a timeout instead of a match. This is because the B0 event arrived before the A-stream's observer had a change to subscribe to the B-stream. I think with a hot B-stream, the prevailing approach of nested subscription is flawed. What is needed is some kind of limited-recent-replay stream - an application for a Subject?

**Solution: Supertopi**

```
package test;

import rx.Observable;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test06Supertopi {
    private static final long A_PERIOD = 400;
    private static final long B_PERIOD = 500;
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 3_000;
    private static final int[] bOrder = {
        0, 1, 2,
        4,
        3,  // out of order
        6,
        5,  // out of order
        7, 8,
        10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        9,  // out of order
        15
    };

    private final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis ();

    public static void main (final String[] args) {
        Test06Supertopi app = new Test06Supertopi ();
        app.runSupertopi ();
    }

    private void runSupertopi () {
        Observable<Long> aStream =
            Observable.interval (A_PERIOD, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .doOnNext (seq -> {
                    output ("       A%s", seq);
                }).take (bOrder.length);

        Observable<Long> bStream =
            Observable.interval (B_PERIOD, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .map (seq -> {
                    long aId = (long) bOrder[seq.intValue ()];
                    output ("           B%s", aId);
                    return aId;
                })
                .take (bOrder.length);

        monitorSupertopi (aStream, bStream, TIMEOUT)
            .subscribe (this::output);

        try {
            Thread.sleep (60_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    private Observable<String> monitorSupertopi (Observable<Long> aStream, Observable<Long> bStream, int thresholdMsec) {
        return Observable.create (subscriber -> {
            Observable<Long> a = aStream.publish ().refCount ();
            Observable<Long> b = bStream.publish ().refCount ();

            a.subscribe ((Long aId) -> {
                Observable.merge (
                    Observable.timer (thresholdMsec, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .doOnNext (x -> {
                            output ("           timeout on B%s", aId);
                        })
                        .map (x -> String.format ("%s,%s", aId, -1L)),
                    b.filter ((Long j) -> j.equals (aId))
                        .map ((Long pbx) -> String.format ("%s,%s", aId, pbx))
                ).take (1)
                .subscribe (subscriber::onNext);
            });
        });
    }

    private void output (String format, Object... args) {
        System.out.printf ("tid:%3d %4dms %s%n", Thread.currentThread ().getId (), System.currentTimeMillis () - startTime,
            String.format (format, args));
    }
}
```

Works fine:

```
private static final long A_PERIOD = 400;
private static final long B_PERIOD = 500;
private static final int TIMEOUT = 4_000;

tid: 14  522ms        A0
tid: 14  922ms        A1
tid: 16 1054ms            B0
tid: 16 1055ms 0,0
tid: 14 1322ms        A2
tid: 16 1555ms            B1
tid: 16 1555ms 1,1
tid: 14 1721ms        A3
tid: 16 2055ms            B2
tid: 16 2055ms 2,2
tid: 14 2122ms        A4
tid: 14 2522ms        A5
tid: 16 2555ms            B4
tid: 16 2555ms 4,4
tid: 14 2922ms        A6
tid: 16 3055ms            B3
tid: 16 3055ms 3,3
tid: 14 3322ms        A7
tid: 16 3555ms            B6
tid: 16 3555ms 6,6
tid: 14 3722ms        A8
tid: 16 4055ms            B5
tid: 16 4055ms 5,5
tid: 14 4122ms        A9
tid: 14 4522ms        A10
tid: 16 4555ms            B7
tid: 16 4555ms 7,7
tid: 14 4922ms        A11
tid: 16 5055ms            B8
tid: 16 5055ms 8,8
tid: 14 5322ms        A12
tid: 16 5555ms            B10
tid: 16 5556ms 10,10
tid: 14 5723ms        A13
tid: 16 6056ms            B11
tid: 16 6057ms 11,11
tid: 14 6122ms        A14
tid: 14 6522ms        A15
tid: 16 6555ms            B12
tid: 16 6555ms 12,12
tid: 16 7055ms            B13
tid: 16 7055ms 13,13
tid: 13 7125ms            timeout on B9
tid: 13 7125ms 9,-1
tid: 16 7555ms            B14
tid: 16 7555ms 14,14
tid: 16 8055ms            B9
tid: 16 8555ms            B15
tid: 16 8555ms 15,15
```

But with closer timings, the initial B events are received twice. I am still investigating this.

```
private static final long A_PERIOD = 400;
private static final long B_PERIOD = 410;
private static final int TIMEOUT = 2_000;

tid: 14  539ms        A0
tid: 14  939ms        A1
tid: 16  983ms            B0
tid: 16  983ms 0,0
tid: 14 1339ms        A2
tid: 16 1393ms            B1
tid: 16 1393ms 1,1
tid: 14 1739ms        A3
tid: 16 1803ms            B2
tid: 16 1803ms 2,2
tid: 14 2139ms        A4
tid: 16 2213ms            B4
tid: 16 2213ms 4,4
tid: 14 2539ms        A5
tid: 16 2623ms            B3
tid: 16 2623ms 3,3
tid: 14 2939ms        A6
tid: 16 3032ms            B6
tid: 16 3032ms 6,6
tid: 14 3339ms        A7
tid: 16 3443ms            B5
tid: 16 3443ms 5,5
tid: 14 3739ms        A8
tid: 16 3852ms            B7
tid: 16 3852ms 7,7
tid: 14 4139ms        A9
tid: 16 4263ms            B8
tid: 16 4263ms 8,8
tid: 14 4539ms        A10
tid: 16 4672ms            B10
tid: 16 4672ms 10,10
tid: 14 4939ms        A11
tid: 16 5083ms            B11
tid: 16 5083ms 11,11
tid: 14 5339ms        A12
tid: 16 5493ms            B12
tid: 16 5493ms 12,12
tid: 14 5739ms        A13
tid: 16 5903ms            B13
tid: 16 5903ms 13,13
tid: 14 6139ms        A14
tid: 13 6140ms            timeout on B9
tid: 13 6140ms 9,-1
tid: 16 6313ms            B14
tid: 16 6313ms 14,14
tid: 14 6539ms        A15
tid: 14 6950ms            B0
tid: 14 7360ms            B1
tid: 14 7770ms            B2
tid: 14 8180ms            B4
tid: 13 8540ms            timeout on B15
tid: 13 8540ms 15,-1
```

**24/2/2016**

**Solution: Lee Campbell**

```
package test;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.subjects.PublishSubject;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class Test06LeeCampbell {
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 500;

    class ScheduledEvent {
        final String type;
        final long aId;
        final long atMsec;
        volatile boolean expired;

        public ScheduledEvent (long atMsec, String type, long aId) {
            this.atMsec = atMsec;
            this.type = type;
            this.aId = aId;
        }
    }

    ScheduledEvent[] scheduledEvents = {
        new ScheduledEvent (10, "A", 0),
        new ScheduledEvent (90, "B", 0),
        new ScheduledEvent (110, "A", 1),
        new ScheduledEvent (140, "B", 1),
        new ScheduledEvent (190, "A", 2),
        new ScheduledEvent (270, "B", 2),
        new ScheduledEvent (310, "A", 3),
        new ScheduledEvent (410, "A", 4),
        new ScheduledEvent (440, "B", 4),
        new ScheduledEvent (480, "B", 3),
        new ScheduledEvent (510, "A", 5),
        new ScheduledEvent (610, "A", 6),
        //new ScheduledEvent (670, "B", 6),
        new ScheduledEvent (710, "A", 7),
        new ScheduledEvent (810, "A", 8),
        new ScheduledEvent (860, "B", 7),
        new ScheduledEvent (880, "B", 8),
        new ScheduledEvent (910, "A", 9),
        new ScheduledEvent (1100, "A", 10),
        new ScheduledEvent (1110, "A", 11),
        new ScheduledEvent (1120, "A", 12),
        new ScheduledEvent (1130, "A", 13),
        new ScheduledEvent (1140, "A", 14),
        //new ScheduledEvent (1200, "B", 10),
        //new ScheduledEvent (1210, "B", 11),
        //new ScheduledEvent (1220, "B", 12),
        new ScheduledEvent (1230, "B", 13),
        new ScheduledEvent (1240, "B", 14),
        new ScheduledEvent (1390, "B", 9),
        new ScheduledEvent (1450, "A", 15),
        new ScheduledEvent (3290, "B", 5),
        new ScheduledEvent (3350, "B", 15)
    };

    private final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis ();

    public static void main (final String[] args) {
        Test06LeeCampbell app = new Test06LeeCampbell ();
        app.runLeeCampbell ();
    }

    private void runLeeCampbell () {
        Observable<Long> aStream =
            getCrudeSequencer ("A")
                .doOnNext (seq -> {
                    output ("       A%s", seq);
                });

        Observable<Long> bStreamCold =
            getCrudeSequencer ("B")
                .doOnNext (seq -> {
                    output ("           B%s", seq);
                });
        PublishSubject<Long> bStream = PublishSubject.create ();
        bStreamCold.subscribe (bStream);

        monitorLeeCampbell (aStream, bStream, TIMEOUT)
            .subscribe (this::output);

        pause (10_000);
    }

    private Observable<String> monitorLeeCampbell (Observable<Long> aStream, Observable<Long> bStream, int thresholdMsec) {
        return aStream.flatMap (a ->
            bStream.filter (b -> b.equals (a))
                .map (b -> String.format ("%s,%s", a, b))
                .take (1)
                .timeout (thresholdMsec, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .onErrorResumeNext (
                    throwable -> {
                        output ("           timeout on B%s", a);
                        if (!(throwable instanceof TimeoutException)) {
                            throw new RuntimeException (throwable);
                        }
                        return Observable.just (String.format ("%s,%s", a, -1L));
                    }
                )
        );
    }

    private void output (String format, Object... args) {
        System.out.printf ("tid:%3d %4dms %s%n", Thread.currentThread ().getId (), getElapsedMsec (),
            String.format (format, args));
    }

    private long getElapsedMsec () {
        return System.currentTimeMillis () - startTime;
    }

    private Observable<Long> getCrudeSequencer (String name) {
        return Observable.create (subscriber ->
            new Thread (() -> {
                for (ScheduledEvent se : scheduledEvents) {
                    if (se.type.equals (name)) {
                        while (getElapsedMsec () < se.atMsec) {
                            pause (1);
                        }
                        subscriber.onNext (Long.valueOf (se.aId));
                        se.expired = true;
                    } else {
                        // Timing is not reliable for sequencing two threads
                        while (!se.expired) {
                            pause (1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                subscriber.onCompleted ();
            }).start ()
        );
    }

    private static void pause (final int millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep (millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

It worked

```
tid: 12   90ms        A0
tid: 11  157ms            B0
tid: 11  157ms 0,0
tid: 12  159ms        A1
tid: 11  160ms            B1
tid: 11  160ms 1,1
tid: 12  190ms        A2
tid: 11  270ms            B2
tid: 11  270ms 2,2
tid: 12  310ms        A3
tid: 12  410ms        A4
tid: 11  440ms            B4
tid: 11  440ms 4,4
tid: 11  480ms            B3
tid: 11  480ms 3,3
tid: 12  510ms        A5
tid: 12  610ms        A6
tid: 12  710ms        A7
tid: 12  810ms        A8
tid: 11  860ms            B7
tid: 11  860ms 7,7
tid: 11  880ms            B8
tid: 11  880ms 8,8
tid: 12  910ms        A9
tid: 15 1011ms            timeout on B5
tid: 15 1012ms 5,-1
tid: 12 1100ms        A10
tid: 12 1110ms        A11
tid: 16 1111ms            timeout on B6
tid: 16 1111ms 6,-1
tid: 12 1120ms        A12
tid: 12 1130ms        A13
tid: 12 1140ms        A14
tid: 11 1230ms            B13
tid: 11 1230ms 13,13
tid: 11 1240ms            B14
tid: 11 1240ms 14,14
tid: 11 1390ms            B9
tid: 11 1390ms 9,9
tid: 12 1450ms        A15
tid: 14 1601ms            timeout on B10
tid: 14 1601ms 10,-1
tid: 15 1611ms            timeout on B11
tid: 15 1611ms 11,-1
tid: 16 1621ms            timeout on B12
tid: 16 1621ms 12,-1
tid: 19 1951ms            timeout on B15
tid: 19 1951ms 15,-1
tid: 11 3290ms            B5
tid: 11 3350ms            B15
```

Comment: Does the B always arrive after its A?

Comment: Yes, B is a follow up to its A.

Comment: I'm not sure to post it as an answer, but it looks rather close http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#replay(rx.functions.Func1,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit).

Comment: Is B in any way triggered by A, or does it come independently?

Comment: can you update your marble diagram to include the out-of-order B value case?

Comment: It appears that your diagram may be wrong. If the match results must be in order, then I infer that you can't have the timeout of A2 after the matching of A3B3. Thus you either need to timeout A2 when the A3B3 match is made, or prevent the yielding of the A3B3 match until the A2 timeout occurs.

Comment: I have added another marble diagram as requested. I appreciate the time you have given to helping me find a solution (and your online book that I have now discovered). The same goes for the other contributors too. One problem I have with understanding the reactive approach to this problem - it seems to me that for every A event the B stream has to be 'observed' starting from that point in time until the corresponding B arrives or timeout.  As with in the second marble diagram, this means the B stream  for B7 and B6 are 'observed' *twice*, and I don't know how to express that in rx operators.

Comment: You wrote "*Thus you either need to timeout A2 when the A3B3 match is made, or prevent the yielding of the A3B3 match until the A2 timeout occurs*". No, I need to match A3B3 while timing out on A2. In fact at any time there can be any number of active timeouts on non-arriving B's, even as arriving B's are matched to A's. This is a natural consequence in the imperative 'traditional' scenario that I gave.

Comment: It appears that Lee's solution works best. I have added it to the original post with output. To test it properly I had to make the B stream hot and provide more control over timing / sequencing of A events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assumptions:

- the B stream is hot,
- You have a return type that can represent a Match or a Mismatch (instead of using OnError/Timeout which will terminate the subscription)

Then this would be fine.

```
AStream.SelectMany(a =>
    BStream.Where(b => b == a)
        .Select(b => new MatchMade(a, b))
        .Take(1)
        .Timeout(matchTimeout)
        .Catch<TimeoutException>(ex=>Observable.Return(new NoMatchMade(a)))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I don't think it will handle the out of order case? eg `(A1, A2, B2, B1, A3, B3)` yielding `(A2B2, A1B1, A3B3)`

Comment: Apologies, I missed that requirement

Comment: And it appears that you requirements are incomplete. See comment on the OP regarding Timeouts

Comment: In both of your marble diagrams you have out of order matches. In the first diagram A2 timeout occurs after A3 is matched. In the second diagram you have A6 matched after A7. It appears that order is of no importance, in which case this answer *I believe* is correct.

Comment: Thanks for following up. OK, if our views of the requirements have converged, I will try to port your solution to rxjava. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have the selective `.Catch<TimeoutException>` capability of rx.net but I will work on that. I will add my findings to the original post.

Comment: I have managed to port to Java and test, improving the test-sequencing of  A and B streams for better control over timeout and out-of-order events. Your solution handled it all. Furthermore, seeing it doesn't require a nested subscription, it is not susceptible to losing fast B events as experienced in Enigmativity's solution. Many thanks for your help. I have learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. The types differ, I didn't want to guess your probably abstract datatypes. You can apply them pretty easily (function parameters, key comparison and `Select` statements)

Idea is that for every emited value from `a`, we take the first value emited either by `b.Where(keys match)` or timeout (presented by `Observable.Timer`) and make our `Select` based on this information.

I assumed that in timeout cases you also want on `OnNext` notification with some error provisioning mechanism.

```
private IObservable<string> MonitorAB(IObservable<long> a, IObservable<long> b,
                                      TimeSpan threshold)
{
    return Observable.Create<string>((obs) =>
    {
        a = a.Publish().RefCount();
        b = b.Publish().RefCount();
        return a.Subscribe(i =>
        {
            Observable.Merge(Observable.Timer(threshold).Select(_ => $"Timeout for A{i}"),
                             b.Where(j => j == i).Select(_ => $"Got matching B for A{i}"))
                      .Take(1)
                      .Subscribe(obs.OnNext);
        });
    });
}
```

I tested it like this.

```
private void Test()
{
    var a = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Take(5);
    var b = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Take(5);
    MonitorAB( a, b, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(13)).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
}
```

EDIT:
to test the out of order case, you can flip the B stream e.g.

```
var b = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Select(i  => 4 - i).Take(5);
```

Comment: Thanks for submitted a tested solution. I have ported it to Java and it works with your timer-based sample streams. I am still assessing it with less regular event timings.

In any case I don't think it will handle the out of order case where a B event arrives out of order from the A events? eg `(A1, A2, B2, B1, A3, B3)` yielding `(A2B2, A1B1, A3B3)`

Comment: @RodneyParnell Thanks for the comment. The order does not matter IF the key comparison in `Where` statement is implemented correctly. If you are having trouble with it, please present your implementation

Comment: Thanks. See the original post for an exploration of your solution.

Comment: @supertopi - There is a potential issue when using `b.Publish().RefCount()` - if all of the subscriptions to `b` are disposed within your query and while the query is still running then any new subscriptions will start a new subscription to the source observable. It's better to use `b.Publish(pb => { /* query here */ })` instead as it doesn't suffer from this weakness.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks. Actually the OP just proved this in his test case. Because of the new subscription to `b` the values of his `map( seq -> ... )` started from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want, albeit it is C# rather than Java - I'm sure you can convert easily enough.

```
private IObservable<string> MonitorAB(
    IObservable<long> a, IObservable<long> b, TimeSpan threshold)
{
    return Observable.Create<string>(o =>
        b.Publish(pb =>
            a.Select(ax =>
                pb.Where(pbx => pbx == ax)
                    .Take(1)
                    .Timeout(threshold, Observable.Return(-1L))
                    .Select(pbx => String.Format("{0},{1}", ax, pbx)))
            .Merge())
            .Subscribe(o));
}
```

So this simply uses the inline `.Publish` to make sure `b` is hot within the query. The outer .`Select` filters the published `pb` observable for those that match the value from `a` (matching `a` & `b`), takes only one cause we only want one, and then does a `.Timeout` for the `threshold` time and returns a `-1L` (`long`) if the timeout is reached. The inner `.Select` just turns the two `long` values into a single `string`. At this point the query is an `IObservable<IObservable<string>>` so the `.Merge` flattens it out.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I believe _(1)_ your merge () call is wrong even in .NET, _(2)_ the second a.Publish () should be b.Publish (), and _(3)_ I am not sure that a.Publish () is necessary since a is only observed once. In any case I don't think it will handle the out of order case? eg `(A1, A2, B2, B1, A3, B3)` yielding `(A2B2, A1B1, A3B3)`

Comment: @RodneyParnell - Good catch on a couple of points. Yes, I should have had `b.Publish(...)` and `a` doesn't need to be published. However, the `.Merge()` call is **correct**, and it does handle the out of order case correctly.

Comment: OK thanks... I will need to work around the lack of a no-args merge () in rxjava. I will report back :-)

Comment: @RodneyParnell - It seems odd that there isn't a no-args merge. It's a fairly core operator.

Comment: @RodneyParnell - The .NET signature is `IObservable<T>` Merge(this IObservable<IObservable<T>> source)`, it is an extension method that really takes a single parameter of a nested observable.

Comment: @RodneyParnell - I looked at the RxJava source and the merge operator is there. It has the signature `static <T> Observable<T> merge(Observable<? extends Observable<? extends T>> source)`.

Comment: Thanks, the extension method threw me, and the Java merge () you identified did the trick. See the original post for an exploration of your solution.